# Arduino to Ubuntu USB connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arduino, arduino-uno

I am having trouble getting an Ubuntu device to connect to an Arduino Uno.  Before I begin talking about the device in question the Arduino is communicating correctly with my Windows pc, and also an Ubuntu VM on that PC.

The device in question is an nVidia Jetson TX2. The Arduino IDE is installed, and when run using sudo the only serial port available is /dev/ttyS0.

The following line is lsusb being run and it detecting the Arduino.

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2341:0001 Arduino SA Uno (CDC ACM)
```

The following lines is the output from dmesg from the time that the Arduino is connected.

```
[ 6609.813385] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci-tegra
[ 6609.923568] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0001
[ 6609.930495] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 6609.938049] usb 1-2.3: Product: Arduino Uno
[ 6609.942268] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 6609.948065] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 7563830333735121D160
[ 6609.953998] usb 1-2.3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
```

And lastly the following is the output from ls -a /dev/tty*

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty18  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty58  /dev/ttyS1
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty19  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty59  /dev/ttyS2
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty2   /dev/tty3   /dev/tty4   /dev/tty5   /dev/tty6   /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty20  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty60  /dev/ttyTHS1
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty61  /dev/ttyTHS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty62
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty63
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty24  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty54  /dev/tty7
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty8
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty56  /dev/tty9
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty57  /dev/ttyS0
```

I don't believe that a driver is being called to create /dev/ttyACM0 but I am not sure how to solve this issue. Any help would be great! Let me know if I need to update with the output from any other commands.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted what the error is but I'm guessing it is an access type error, have you done the part at the end of the install for linux?

At the end of https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux there is section on permissions for the serial port.

Comment: I have set the permissions but there is currently no point to it because /dev/ttyACM0 doesn't exist to even attempt to communicate with.

Comment: Have you seen the part about the tty at the end of this section? http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Linux  If yours is looking for the ACM it looks like you have to have set the USB modem connection.